# Batch script not running at startup using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-7, python, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have written a simple batch script [`E:\Project Artemis\startup.bat`] to start Python SimpleHTTPServer at startup of Windows 7, with the script working when I manually execute it, but after adding it to Task Scheduler to launch at system startup, it does not do so (Task Scheduler shows the process ran and it's status as *ready*)

```bat
@ECHO OFF 
pushd E:\Project Artemis\Wave 
python -m http.server
```

- When I try to run it from Task Scheduler manually, the script does not work and History shows the task was completed with return code `1`, meaning something went wrong, but provides no details: 
   [image: Screenshot2]

  - Directory `Project Artemis` contains multiple files and I added `E:\Project Artemis\` to the task's `Start in(optional)` parameter

How do I troubleshoot this and is there another way to start Python SimpleHTTPServer at startup?

Comment: is `E:` available at startup or is this a user disk? enable the task history and see what it says (if it was run, was an error encountered,...)

Comment: @Zina , E: is available at startup. It's a hard disk partition.

Comment: @Zina, task status is ready. Summary says no task failed. This is the final history log:      ---------  Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Focus Localhost" , instance "{de8b31a4-9e9e-4d18-8e6b-5274ab69144f}" , action "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" with return code 1.

Comment: @Zina Isn't return code 1 bad? Doesn't it mean there was an error?

Comment: yes, 1 is some error, I would use full paths for the commands you use (pushd & python - the path might not be active) and I always try not to use space characters in paths - maybe you need to enclose them between quotes. another thing you can do add some logging into a file (full path) into your script to see what works and what not and to test it faster you can try to run with time in future (a few mins) so you don't have to restart your computer for each test run

Comment: Solved the problem. User should not be SYSTEM.

Comment: @AlphaDelta `System` shouldn't be used to execute an executable, as that then provides the executable `System` level permissions, which only a handful of executables should ever have, most dealing with VSS and system updating/servicing. Just an FYI for future reference, please include the XML output of the task _(export the task and open in a text editor, pasting the content into a code box)_, as that allows for more efficient [faster] troubleshooting.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @AlphaDelta you can post that as the answer down below to help others who may have the same issue.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for the suggestion. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question for future readers as per suggestion of @music2myear.

[image]

As it is visible in the screenshot, I had set the user as SYSTEM to give the task high privilege. But due to some reason this interfered with the ability of the task to run and I am not sure why. Even if I were to run it from task scheduler window, it would not work.

However after fiddling around, I found that if the User Account to run the task is NOT set to SYSTEM, the task runs perfectly.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Good. This is good for others with the same question, and for you because you'll get reputation score for this. Sweet, sweet reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an `.exe` that opens the `.bat`,  then pin the `.exe` to the Startup menu.

Comment: Task Scheduler can run .bat files just fine without needing them to be packaged in an exe. It's possible you may wish to call command.com, but that shouldn't be necessary. As OP noted, they already solved the problem when they learned the User account running the task cannot be System. It can be helpful to read the comments on the question in order to avoid giving incorrect information.